# Como concatenar variável com fórmula no Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, concatenação-de-string

Está correto eu concatenar uma variável a uma fórmula do Excel?

O Excel reclama no fechamento da concatenação:

```
Sheets("FATURA").Select
Dim variavel As Double
variavel = InputBox("Digite Valor da Tarifa caso nao souber Digite 0,35")               
MsgBox ("Valor sem desconto: " & variavel)
Range("Z2:Z" & Range("I1048576").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=RC[-1]&IF(RC[-2]< " &variavel& ,""M"",""O"")"
```

Comment: Tentei formatar teu código, mas não faço ideia se tá certo. Você pode clicar em [edit] e formatá-lo.

Answer (score 1):

Marcio, boa tarde!

Na  minha visão sim é possível e esta certo, pois se faz necessário  conforme sua necessidade de dinamismo ao construir a fórmula. Então sege minha sugestão de como creio que funcionará:

```
Sheets("FATURA").Select

Dim variavel As Double

variavel = InputBox("Digite Valor da Tarifa caso não souber Digite 0,35")               

MsgBox ("Valor sem desconto: " & variavel)

Range("Z2:Z" & Range("I1048576").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=RC[-1]&IF(RC[-2]< " & variavel & ," & chr(34) & "M" & chr34) & "," & chr(34) & "O" & chr(34) & ")"
```

Comment: Bacana amigo vou testar

Comment: Joguei o Resultado em uma célula e fiz o calculo a partir da mesmo q resolveu meu problema